# redundant command line of javascript program?

Tags: javascript

I am newbie with javascript and I wrote a very simple program to display something using function and alert. Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var balance = 10500;
var cameraOn = true;
function steal(balance, amount){
cameraOn = false;
if (amount < balance) {
balance = balance - amount;
}
return amount;
cameraOn = true;
}
var amount = steal(balance, 1250);
alert("Criminal: you stole " + amount + "!");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The code is ok, when I ran it, it display "Criminal: you stole 1250!" as I expected. But, my problem is, in my code as you can see, there is a code `cameraOn = true;` I do not know why I must write this code ( I copy this code from the book I studied ).

When I made this line to be referenced, the result did not change. So, I thought that this code is not necessary ?

Could you please give me some ideas for me with this problem ? Thank you very much.

Comment: switching off the camera before stealing

Comment: _"I do not know why I must write this code"_ - If that line is at the same spot in the book, then you should get another book. Anything after `return ...;` won't be executed.

Comment: The book should have explained this. It's just a variable standing in for actually turning a camera off and turning it back on. (It probably should have been a function call, but then you'd have to have the function to call, which would further complicate the example.)

Answer (score 0):

It's not executed since it's written after the "return" keyword.
So yes, you can (you should) delete this line.